# Populating column based on existing columns in MySQL 5.6 and ORACLE 11 and ORACLE 12

Tags: mysql, oracle

I have a table where one column is of varchar type which contains value as '1.2.1', '1', '0.2' etc.

In general there will be max 3 numbers separated by decimal (.)

I need to create 3 new columns of Integer type to save these 3 numbers.

Sample data looks like this.

[image: Sample data looks like this]

Also, the data can contain some string value as well but its fixed that it will be one string appended at last, separated by hyphen (-). For Example 1.2.1-xyz. If the data is like this, the string value should go to fourth column.

This case data will look like below:

[image]

This is the query which I have written to achieve this requirement.

Please find below the SQLFiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5aaeb4/1

Is there any better way of doing this? I am new to DB side so please suggest some optimized approach of achieving this.

Comment: Do you want answer all the three RDBMS ? This is Too Broad. Consider converting this into three questions - one for each RDBMS (and specific version).

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I am basically looking for approach here. If I can get the best approach for one RDBMS, may be I can follow the same for others as well. As you can see the fiddle I have posted is of MySQL5.6. I am taking it as base as of now. But my application supports all these 3 DBs so need to do for all.

Comment: You are looking to update the table, or dynamically select the new columns ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I need to update the columns. Actually these are newly added columns so I need to populate them for the existing records.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, we can use [`Substring_Index()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function as well as [User-defined variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html). Variables help us in avoiding redoing certain string operations again and again.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table1` (
  `mainCol` varchar(45) NOT NULL 
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `table1` (`mainCol`) VALUES
  ('1.2.1'),
  ('0.2'),
  ('1'), 
  ('1.2.1-xyz'),
  ('1.2');
```

---

**Query**

```
SELECT 
  mainCol, 

  @first := SUBSTRING_INDEX(mainCol, '.', 1) AS col1, 

  TRIM(LEADING '.' FROM 
       REPLACE(@second := SUBSTRING_INDEX(mainCol, '.', 2), 
               @first,
               '')
      ) AS col2,  

  @fourth := CASE WHEN INSTR(mainCol, '-') 
                  THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(mainCol, '-', -1)
                  ELSE ''
             END AS col4, 

  REPLACE(TRIM(LEADING '.' FROM 
               REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(mainCol, '.', 3), 
                       @second,
                       '')
               ), 
          CONCAT('-', @fourth), 
          '') AS col3 
FROM table1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @first := '', 
                   @second := '', 
                   @third := '',
                   @fourth := '') AS user_vars;
```

**Result**

```
| mainCol   | col1 | col2 | col4 | col3 |
| --------- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- |
| 1.2.1     | 1    | 2    |      | 1    |
| 0.2       | 0    | 2    |      |      |
| 1         | 1    |      |      |      |
| 1.2.1-xyz | 1    | 2    | xyz  | 1    |
| 1.2       | 1    | 2    |      |      |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fAtYSJ49QRndmVqa5zvNmm/1)